# How to get a gaussian distributed random variable?

Tags: random, prolog, gaussian

I need to do something like this

```
personstrength(P) ~ gaussian(10,3) :- person(P).
winner(A,B) :- personstrength(A) > personstrength(B).
```

I want the strength of the person to be gaussian distributed with expected value 10 and variance 3. How do I do this in prolog?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know prolog, but it looks like the [plrand](http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/SamerAbdallah/) library may be of interest to you.

Note that since all persons have the same scaling, unless you want to keep the strength attribute around for later you can just use standard normals. Person A will have strength S<sub>A</sub> = (sqrt(3) * G<sub>A</sub> + 10), person B will have S<sub>B</sub> = (sqrt(3) * G<sub>B</sub> + 10), so S<sub>A</sub> > S<sub>B</sub> if and only if G<sub>A</sub> > G<sub>B</sub>.